# How do I get a QR code to from my telerik app-builder project so that I can scan it and preview the application from my device?

Tags: telerik, qr-code, telerik-appbuilder

I have the Telerik AppBuilder Companion App which allows for previewing an app by scanning a QR code. My issue is, I don't know where to find a code for my project. How can I generate this QR code from the Telerik tools in my visual studio project?

Thank you very much for your time. Let me know if I'm being unclear or if you need any additional information from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the AppBuilder menu and choose "Build [project] in Cloud". This will bring up a dialog and let you choose to run your app in one of the Companion Apps.